# Pass Term object to theme

Tags: 9

In my controller, I have a function that gets a taxonomy term. If I pass the term name to my theme function (`$current_type = $term->name;`), that works.

```
$roots = $this->termStorage->loadTree(ProductsController::PRIMARY_CATEGORIES, 0, 1, FALSE);
$current_type = null;
foreach ($roots as $term){
  if($this->urlSafeTerm($term->name) == $category){
    // $current_type = $term->name;
    $current_type = Term::load($term->tid);
    break;
  }
}
    
$build = [
  '#theme' => 'product_category',
  '#type' => $current_type,
  ],
];

return $build;
```

In my hook_theme function:

```
'product_category' => [
  'template' => 'products/category',
  'variables' => [
    'type' => NULL,
],
```

But if I try to load the term object (`$current_type = Term::load($term->tid);`) and pass that, I gives me:

```
TypeError: Illegal offset type in Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo() (line 79 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/ElementInfoManager.php)
```

Is it not possible to pass a Term entity like this or is there something else I'm missing and/or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a different template variable name, `#type` is used for render elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a render array, *#type* is already a property used by Drupal, which cannot be used for other purposes from a theme hook. It's the machine name of the type of render/form element.
For example, in the following code, *#type* is what allows Drupal to understand that the first item is a detail element and the second one is a text field.

```php
$form['author'] = array(
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => >t('Author'),
);
$form['author']['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Name'),
);
```

When Drupal finds *#type* in a render array, it will ask to the element plugin manager information about the element plugin to use. (See [`ElementInfoManager::getInfo()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21ElementInfoManager.php/function/ElementInfoManager%3A%3AgetInfo/9.3.x).) With the wrong value, it throws the exception you are seeing.

The solution is replacing *type* with a string that isn't already used by Drupal. [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/9.3.x) (where the purpose of *#type* and *#theme* is explained) and the documentation for [`RenderElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21RenderElement.php/class/RenderElement/9.3.x) show a list of properties already used by Drupal.
For example, replacing *type* with *term_id* should fix that error.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.